# How to detach from docker by sending Ctrl+P & Ctrl+Q through telnet using python?

Tags: python, docker, keyboard-shortcuts

I have connected to a system via telnet and then launched a docker on that system using below command

```
docker run  -it ubuntu bash
```

The docker is launched successfully and now I want to detach from docker by sending Ctrl+P & Ctrl+Q keys via my python script. I do send the '\x10' & '\x11' for the same but the docker is not detached. I can't use "exit" command since I want to reattach to the docker at later point in the script.

Code snippet

```
conn = telnetlib.Telnet(SOME_IP, SOME_PORT)
conn.write('ls\n')
conn.read_very_eager() # Getting proper output

# Tried all of below combinations but nothing works
ctrl_p_q_1, ctrl_p_q_2, ctrl_p, ctrl_q = '\x10\x11', '\x10\x11\n', '\x10', '\x11' 
conn.write(ctrl_p_q_1)
conn.write(ctrl_p_q_2)
conn.write(ctrl_p)
conn.write(ctrl_q)
conn.write(ctrl_p)
conn.write(ctrl_q+'\n')
```

Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: What is the program you're trying to run in the container?  Can you directly run that program as a custom image's `CMD`, maybe using the `docker run -d` option to launch it in the background, instead of trying to detach from an interactive shell?

Comment: I need to check the number of network interfaces so would need the output of my command(ifconfig) as well. Depending on the output, I need to take further decision in the code.

Comment: A Docker container doesn't really have network interfaces in any useful way (there is a loopback interface and an external interface but both are fully managed by Docker).  What's your higher-level goal with this setup?  Why can't the container do it itself?

Comment: I know docker container doesn't have any network interfaces but we can attach the network interfaces of host system to docker using pipework command. Anyways, the question here is how to detach the container(using Ctrl+P & Ctrl+Q) via python script.